# Відповідник до слова "офшор"

Tags: вибір-слова, іншомовні-слова

**Офшор** - територія або країна, що має привабливо низькі або нульові ставки на всі чи деякі види прибутків іноземних компаній.

**Приклад вживання:**

> Понад половини світової торгівлі йде через офшори.

На [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/ofshor) пропонують варіант "позаподатковий", однак ми не можемо замінити прикметником іменник. Також там є слово "безподаття", однак в СУМі слова "подаття" немає і як бути в такмоу випадку із іменниками множини (офшор-офшори)? Слово "забережжя" як на мене не повністю передає значення слова "офшор" і може означати просто "щось, що знаходиться за берегом".

Тому чи є в наші мові якісь влучні відповідники (напевно, це повинен бути якийсь економічний термін) або ж чи можна їх створити так, щоб вони не суперечили правилам українського словотвору та повною мірою передавали значення слова-оригінала?

Comment: Слід взяти до уваги, що це не просто іноземне слово, і не тільки економічний термін, а і юридичний, до того ж міжнародний, що використовується у всьому світі, у міжнародних організаціях, і в більшості країн, в т.ч. в Україні. Термін офшор вже закріплений в нашому [законодавстві](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/find/a?text=%EE%F4%F8%EE%F0&textl=1&bool=and). Поза економічним/юридичним контекстом термін майже не вживається. Тому шукати чи  придумувати відповідники на кшталт 'забережжя' все ж не варто - жоден перекладач з укр на іноземну, не носій української, навряд чи зможе перекласти правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Відповідповідник до слово "офшор" швидше за все буде неологізмом, адже це слово теж прийшло до нас зовсім недавно.

Якщо говорити про варіант "забережжя", то він буде найближчим до оригіналу за способом творення, адже, як пише у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%84%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%80):

> **Офшо́р** - англ. offshore — **«поза берегом»**, **«поза межами»**.

Отож звідси й утворено забережжя.

Такий же відповідник пропонує і Кирилюк О. Л. у статті ["ДО ПИТАННЯ ПРО УКРАЇНСЬКІ НЕОЛОГІЗМИ – ЗАМІННИКИ ІНШОМОВНИХ СЛІВ"](http://www.apriori-nauka.ru/media/slovo/11-2016/Kirilyuk.pdf):

> **офшор** – ***забережжя***.

Отже, найкраще, як вже писала п. Mariia Matskevych, використовувати таки слово ***"офшор"***, однак якщо вже хочеться саме відповідник-неологізм, тоді варто зупинитися на лексемі ***"забережжя"***.

Answer (score 5):

термін ***"офшор"*** присутній в декількох академічних виданнях:

**[Eкономічна енциклопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/38/53406/382661.html)**

> ***ОФШОР*** залучення іноземного капіталу з метою пожвавлення економічного розвитку країни шляхом податкових та інших пільг
> іноземним резидентам.

**[Економічний словник](http://slovopedia.org.ua/105/53406/1092984.html)**

> ***ОФШОР*** (англ. *оff shore*)   центри спільного підприємництва, які надають пільговий режим фінансово-кредитних операцій в іноземній
> валюті для іноземних резидентів.

[ВТССУМ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53406/932399.html)

> ***ОФШОР***  -у, ч. **1.** Території, які забезпечують пільговий режим (зниження податків, звільнення від валютного контролю і т. ін.) для
> фінансово-кредитних операцій із закордонними учасниками в іноземній
> валюті. **2.** Термін, що його застосовують для характеристики деяких
> видів банківських операцій.

Можемо використовувати саме слово ***"офшор"*** не замінюючи на інші слова.